# Dropbox list_folder api javascript not working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dropbox, dropbox-api

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'String';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var response = xhr.response;
    console.log(response);
  }
};
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
  path: '/lol'
}));
xhr.send();
```

I can't figure out what seems wrong in the code. Any Help?

Comment: What isn't working exactly? What response do you get?

Comment: I am getting a *has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at documentation for [list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) - that endpoint is a RPC endpoint:

> These endpoints accept arguments as JSON in the request body and return results as JSON in the response body. RPC endpoints are on the api.dropboxapi.com domain.

`Dropbox-API-Arg` header seems to be used for `Content-upload` and `Content-download` type endpoints

I do not see anything about a header called `Dropbox-API-Arg` needed for `/files/list_folder` endpoint. Try something like

```
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({path:"/lol"}));
```

Comment: I am getting a *has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*